# How to Link html & PHP program

Tags: php, html, eclipse

I am struggling to resolve a very easy task. I am very new to programming of any nature. Appreciate help.

1: I am passing below URL from a form to a .php code
http://localhost:8080/StaticLoginPage/FormProcessor.php?uname=mandar

2: PHP Code below - In this code I am not able to print uname on the page. Output only displays Welcome and no uname.

3: Additional info:
I am using Eclipse latest version
I am working in "Static Web project"

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["uname"]; ?><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share code in FormProcessor.php file.

Comment: Always enable error reporting, add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your PHP scripts and see if it yields any error or not. Also, do `var_dump($_GET);` to see the complete superglobal structure.

Answer (score 2):

To to this you have to run your code in a php server like apache. the following link might help.

http://editrocket.com/articles/php_apache_windows.html

Answer (score 0):

you need a php server like apache to use php and you need to save your file as a .php file